# Jquery data returning undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to retrieve the data using jquery, but I keep on getting undefined as the value. The html code is being echoed to the document by a PHP function. Thanks

```
<td data-id='332'>
  <i class="fa fa-trash delSubCat"></i>
  <a href='#'>Validate</a>
</td>

$(document).on('ready',function(){
  $(this).on('click',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this).parent().data("id"));
  });

});
```

Comment: Doesn't look like your outer `this` references anything (perhaps the document).  You want the click on the `a` or just anywhere?

Comment: I would like 'this' to reference either the <i></i> or the <a></a> tags

Comment: I got it! Haha thanks for that I understood the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problem

1) You didn't follow the hierarchy of table and tr above td and therefore it is not getting rendered properly.

2) You added listener on this instead of

```
 <table>
      <tr>
    <td data-id='332'>
      <i class="fa fa-trash delSubCat"></i>
      <a href='#'>Validate</a>
    </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

JS

```
  $('a').on('click',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this).parent().data("id"));
  });
```

Working jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lbagfn7o/

Comment: Cool then close this question :). If needed you can select my answer as solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `<table>` tag that's why the parent of `a` becomes body because of invalid structure

```js
$(document).on('ready',function(){
  $('a').on('click',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this).parent().data('id'));
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>

<td data-id='332'>
  <i class="fa fa-trash delSubCat"></i>
  <a href='#'>Validate</a>
</td>

</table>
```